# check if the json file string is empty in bash script

Tags: json, linux, string, bash, shell

HI my Json file is as follows:

```
{
    "num_sensor" : 1,
    "J2" : {"B" : "sensor0", "A" : "sensor1", "D" : "sensor2" , "C" : "sensor3"},
    "J1" : {"B" : "", "A" : "sensor5", "D" : "sensor6" , "C" : "sensor7"} 
}
```

I tried the following to check J1.B is empty:

```
s=`jq '.J1.B' ~/package/sensor_data.json`
```

With the following methods:

```
if [[ $s = """" ]];
then
echo "empty"
else
echo "not_empty"
echo "$s"
fi

jq -r '.[] | if .J1.B == ""
                   then "description is empty"
                   else .J1.B end' ~/package/sensor_data.json

k=`jq '.J1.B' ~/package/sensor_data.json select (.!=null)`
echo "$k"

if [ -z "$s" ]
then
      echo "\$var is empty"
      
else
      echo "\$var is NOT empty"
      echo "$s"
fi
```

None of them work. Everything gives me non-empty and

```
jq -r '.[] | if .J1.B == ""
                   then "description is empty"
                   else .J1.B end' ~/package/sensor_data.json
```

gives me Error as:

```
 Cannot index number with string "J1"
```

Can you please let me know how I can check empty string of json file in bash script?

Comment: Unrelated to your error message: In `$s = """"` the string `""""` is interpreted as the empty string -- no, not two quotes `""` but literally the empty string. You probably meant `'""'` or `\"\"`.

Comment: Thank you @Socowi that works but if the string is "  " with some space again I need to make a conditional statement with the space. Is there any other method to know if the string is empty?

Comment: Json string is not a list so can't be indexed. I would try removing `.[]` .

Comment: Thanks @LMC that works too. But as decribed above what if there is a empty space between the quotes. I dont want to create a new if condition to check that too.

Comment: Use a regular expression to test if it's any number of spaces.

Comment: You might be able to use bash parameter expansion to remove all spaces as part of your `if [ -z "$s" ]` check.  Something like `if [ -z "${s/ /}" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading and trailing spaces (if any) and test for empty string

```
echo '{"J1" : {"B" : ""} }' | jq 'if((.J1.B | gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"")) == "") then "empty" else .J1.B end'
"empty"

echo '{"J1" : {"B" : "  "} }' | jq 'if((.J1.B | gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"")) == "") then "empty" else .J1.B end'
"empty"

echo '{"J1" : {"B" : " a"} }' | jq 'if((.J1.B | gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"")) == "") then "empty" else .J1.B end'
" a"
```

Comment: if I want to make a dir for J1.A, I am getting "sensor1" as directory name but not sensor1 just the name without quotes. what should I do for this?

Comment: That's a different question. Please make a different question for it.

Comment: thanks it works instead of empty at last you need to put the locoation of the json file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here.  The first thing to note is that this expression is returning `""`, not an empty string.  That is, it's returing a string with 2 double quotes:

```
$ jq .J1.B json
""
```

And so, this expression yields nothing:

```
$ s=$(jq .J1.B json)
$  [ -z "$s" ]  && echo empty
```

`empty` is NOT printed because `s` is not empty.  It actually contains the string `""`.

There are a couple ways of addressing this.  My preferred method is just to pass the `-r` (raw) flag to jq:

```
$ s=$(jq  -r  .J1.B json) ;  [ -z "$s" ]  && echo empty
empty
```

Here's another approach:  Compare to double quotes:

```
$ s=$(jq  .J1.B json) ; [ "$s" == '""' ]  && echo empty
empty
```

Above, you can see a quoted the string with single quotes.  Using `""""` is a bad practice - since that evaluates to an empty string next to another empty string (still of length 0).

```
$ a=""""; echo ${#a}
0
```